# Technically Sound vs. Technically Strong/Good. Which one has more value technically?

Tags: comparison

I got a statement from my colleagues saying I'm technically sound. Usually they used to say “technically strong” or “technically good” to refer to others but when referring to me they said “I'm technically sound”. So I just want to know the difference between Technically Sound and Technically Strong/Technically Good in terms of referring to a knowledge of a person.

Comment: I would say it means the same thing, essentially. The foundation of technical knowledge on which you metaphorically stand is structurally sound.